# sdk error running an app on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

hey guys im trying to ru my emulator but when I run it , its giving me this error:

"Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: /Users/nunofernandes/Library/Android/sdk
"

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Tools > SDK Manager you can select and download the required SDK, and in doing so you'll be prompted to accept the license agreement. Doing so should prevent this error.

Comment: Hi, thanks it worked but now im having another issue. When i make it to run the app it say´s starting  avd, and does not open the emulator...